# Error using algorithm in LyX

Tags: lyx, algorithms

I'm trying to insert `Float -> Algorithm`, but error occurs.

it looks like I'm missing `\endgroup`, but I'm not sure how to fix it (pretty new to LyX).

Preamble preview:

```
%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{אלגוריתם}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newenvironment{lyxcode}
    {\par\begin{list}{}{
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}
        \setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}% needed for AMS classes
        \raggedright
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
        \normalfont\ttfamily}%
     \item[]}
    {\end{list}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{אלגוריתם}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You say that "an error occurs", can you be more precise? What is the error? Where does it occur? Also, your example is helpful, but it would be really more helpful if it was _complete_, that is, if it could be directly compiled. This way, others could simply copy-paste it and run it to see the error you're getting.

Comment: The error is “Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup”, and it only appears after creating an algorithm. And also how can I copy the "complete" version? Sorry, I am really new to this :) @Vincent

Comment: @Ludwig welcome to tex.se! As for a complete version, export the .lyx file to LaTeX and post the entire contents of that file. Please in addition post the .lyx file itself of a minimal example. For more information, please read this: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample